# Migrating my .net wpf application from .net 4.5 to 4.0 along with sqlite? Sqlite reference is not getting resolved

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite

I am downgrading my .net project targeted on .net4.5 to .net 4.0. I have SQlite DLLs being used in this project. when i changed target framework in project properties. biuld errors came as:

> Error 11  The type or namespace name 'SQLite' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\Users\nehat\Desktop\skillmeterTrial\SkillMeter\SkillMeter\DataAccessLayer\DataAccessADO.cs   10  19  SkillMeter
>   Error 12  The type or namespace name 'SQLite' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\Users\nehat\Desktop\skillmeterTrial\SkillMeter\SkillMeter\DataAccessLayer\SQLiteHelper.cs    10  19  SkillMeter
>   Error 13  The type or namespace name 'SQLiteConnection' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\Users\nehat\Desktop\skillmeterTrial\SkillMeter\SkillMeter\DataAccessLayer\SQLiteHelper.cs    30  24  SkillMeter

Though i have added dlls downloaded from sqlite.org. I am not able to find out the solution to thi. Can Somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the System.Data.SQLite DLLs?

You need to use sqLite dlls which are compatible with .Net 4.0. (Probably you are using the DLLs which are compatible with 4.5).

[Visit  System.Data.SQLite download page](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Download the new DLLs (.net 4.0 supported) and remove old DLLs from project and new ones.

Comment: I have downloaded the dlls for .NET framework 4 from website and added them as well. Still the problem persists..Do i need to make any changes to the app.config file for this?